Angular Material Cannot Apply Border Radius = 0
This is how it looks now.
I want to remove the bottom radius. I've tried several different CSS changes, but to no avail.
forms.scss
.mdc-notched-outline__leading, .mdc-notched-outline__notch, .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 0;
}

/*  .mdc-text-field--outlined mdc-text-field--no-label {
    border-radius: 0;
}*/
/*  .mdc-notched-outline__trailing {
    border-bottom-right-radius: !important 0;
}

.mdc-notched-outline__leading {
    border-bottom-left-radius: !important 0;
}*/
/*  .mdc-notched-outline__leading{
    border-bottom-left-radius: !important 0px;
}*/

HTML
<div>
    <!-- Pagination -->
    <mat-paginator class="no-wrap"
        *ngIf="isPageable"
        [pageSizeOptions]="paginationSizes"
        [pageSize]="defaultPageSize"
        showFirstLastButtons>
    </mat-paginator>
</div>

Angular Material v17

Check whether your styles are being applied after the material import. I would recommend moving it to styles.scss and check the angular.json the order of the styles imports. Yours need to be last

@CaioOliveira, moving to styles.scss fixed it. Thanks very much!

While moving to styles.scss will work, it will become global. Same with ng-deep.
If you don't want the style to leak, you can give the element a class, and use ng-deep OR styles.scss with the class name.
Using styles.scss will usually cause longer compiling time on ng serve due to the style being applied globally.

Moving the response here for others to see:
Check whether your styles are being applied after the material import. I would recommend moving it to styles.scss and check the angular.json the order of the styles imports. Yours need to be last

I don't know if this still work on the new angular versions, but try using.
for details , angular does not recognise the classes of angular material out of component scope.
:host::ng-deep .className {
 border-radius : none ;
}


Didn't seem to work.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
